# dimmed area missplacement when using UISearchDisplayController with translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When I switch navigationBar to translucent, my UISearchDisplayController went crazy.

The dimmed area is missplaced by 64px, same for first row in results table.
I know how to fix resultTableView missplacement, but I cannot find a way to fix dimmed area frame.

Strangely enough I found that my main view is in origin.y = 64.0f when translucent is set to YES.
It happens somewhere in between viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear. If I change it it works, but than transitions between views in navigations controller are broken.

[image]

=============

Problem solved by: extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the search bar's AutoLayout/AutoResizingMask settings.

Also make sure you're not manually modifying the bar's frame as the system will try to animate the bar into its position along the dimmed view and results' table view.

---

When you set the `translucent` property and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `YES` (default): a) the view gets stretched under the navigation bar and b) a top `contentInset` is added to the underlying `UIScrollView` (table view is a subclass).

My guess is that only b) is happening in your case for some reason. You can try to solve it by either:

- Clear `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`.
- Removing the automatically added `contentInset` from your scroll view.
- Setting your controller to do a) even with opaque bars by setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`.

Comment: search bar is inside navigation bar, does it matter how it's resized ? I'm modifying top bar frame in facebook style, when use scroll, it hides. But that doesn't matter. Problem is that when I set translucent = YES (which is default) it works.

Comment: extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars fixed the problem ! You are my hero :) Spend so much time on that and never found this property. Thx again.